# Conditional Formatting of Row based on multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am trying to write a formula that will cover A3:AB311, where col f:L has checkboxes and N:AB have dates that are filled in. I want to highlight the entirety of a row if all the boxes in F:L are checked and there is text in each cell in N:AB.

Here is the formula that I have come up with but it only highlights F:L and even then just whichever ones are checked, not if all are checked.

`=AND($F3:$L3 = TRUE, NOT(ISBLANK($N3:$T3)), NOT(ISBLANK($V3:$AB3)))`

here is a scrubbed version of the doc that I am working with.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15lsA-by2vJOzp8N-_9NxLkkSmYPMAvRcVQ9Gb7KMj-Y/edit?usp=sharing

Line 31 is the only one that should be highlighted

Id really appreciate any assistance you guys could offer, ive been working on this off and on for a few days now.

Comment: Make your sheet editable.

Comment: Thats a goof on my part, whoops. Luckily Carlos was able to answer it for me anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=AND($F3:$L3,counta($N3:$T3)=columns($N3:$T3),counta($V3:$AB3)=columns($V3:$AB3))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I had missed the counta formula completely. Thats a lot easier than trying to do NOT(ISBLANK). Seriously thanks a lot man.

Comment: Very much appreciated!